# Cookie Based Authentication - Creating a secure response header

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies

I am implementing cookie based authentication on my tls webserver. Though I am still a bit unsure if this response header creates a secure cookie based authentication?

My goal is to disable CORS and prevent XSS and other known exploits

These are my headers (in dictionary form).

```cpp
token = "...";
origin = "https://localhost:8000";
headers = {
    "Set-Cookie": "T=" + token + "; Path=/; Max-Age=3600; Expires=True; SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly;",
    "Origin": origin,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": origin,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS",
    "Vary": "Origin",
    "Cache": "no-cache",
    "Connection": "close",
};
```

Is there anything I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: You sure this is C++? What's a `String`? What's a `Dict`? `toString`?

Comment: @user4581301 My own classes. I will remove the c++ tag and code.

Comment: Apologies. Those edits may not have been unnecessary. I was worried you'd mistagged C# code or something similar.